# find the word and highlight that with str_replace

Tags: php, regex

I’m trying to find a keyword (ex. “star wars”) in a paragraph string (ex. “I bought my lucky star a new wars bone and he loves it.”. and highlight that between  tags

my problem is everytime my keywords have 2 words like `star wars` str_replace find exactly `star wars` i want find separately `star` and `wars` and then highlight that...

```
   $text="star mama say wars"
   $keyword="star wars"
   $newkeyword = explode(" ", $keyword);
   $text = str_replace($newkeyword, "<strong>$newkeyword</strong>", $text);
   OUTPUT=<strong>array</strong>
```

i want to...

```
    OUTPUT=<strong>star</strong> <strong>wars</strong>
```

thanks for your helps....

Comment: So, why didn't https://3v4l.org/nRpWZ work? ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482773/how-can-i-extract-the-word-seperate-space-and#comment103297091_58482773))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't work as OP intended, i.e when using `star movie wars` or OPs example phrase

Comment: @kerbholz I doubt it is the real expected output. `$text` looks ignored then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I would rather build a single pattern for `preg_replace` than doing a loop.

```
$pattern = '~\b(?:'.preg_replace('~[^\w\'-]+~', "|", $keyword).')\b~i';
```

In this pattern we replace all characters [that are not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `\w` a *word character*, a single quote or a hyphen by a pipe, put it into a [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) sorrounded by [word boundaries `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and use `i` [flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for caseless matching if desired. So the pattern is [`~\b(?:star|wars)\b~i`](https://regex101.com/r/8t0NNz/1). Further add `u` flag if input is UTF-8.

And do the replacement:

```
$text = preg_replace($pattern, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
```

Where `$0` is a reference to the full match. Using a capture in the replacement has the advantage of not changing the original case (upper/lower).

[Here is a PHP demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/quE0E)

Comment: @BijanZand how do you mean? :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use preg_replace and make sure it's complete words with `\b` before making a replace or it will replace when you write say `starring`

```
$text="some film is starring a movie star with wars";
$keyword="star wars";
$newkeyword = explode(" ", $keyword);

foreach ($newkeyword as $key => $value) {
    $text = preg_replace("/\b" .  $value . "\b/", "<strong>$value</strong>", $text);
}

echo $text;
```

https://3v4l.org/finkZ

Answer (score 0):

Use `loop` for find and replace keywords:

```
  $text="star mama say wars"
  $keyword="star wars"
  $newkeyword = explode(" ", $keyword);

  foreach ($newkeyword as $key => $value) {
    $text = str_replace($value, "<strong>$value</strong>", $text);
  }
```